Does the rate of change of blood pressure depend on cardiovascular fitness?
For example, going from sitting to standing can raise blood pressure. Does the rate of that change depend on cardiovascular fitness? Like, does a more fit person reach their standing blood pressure faster?

From personal experience, sadly now long ago, my then 30 bpm heart rate generally resulted in a slow change in blood pressure as monitored by slight dizziness on standing rapidly.

@JonCuster Orthostatic hypotension AKA postural hypotension is the term for the delay in blood pressure change with standing up. Incredibly common in the general population; about 25% people have it once over 60, though less than 5% under 45. I've been in a similar situation when younger and more athletic than I am now.

@bob1 - correct, the point I was trying to make is that a slow heart rate leads to a long time for feedback. The time it takes me to stand up is less than 2 seconds, and if the heart contracts every 2 seconds it can be a long time, subjectively, to stand there feeling woozy.
